# Transpose Multiple columns into 2 columns

Tags: ms-access

Would like to keep the ID, but transpose each product column to 1 products column.
From

```
ID      Product 1   Product 2   Product 3
1111    Apple       Cherry      Peach
2222                            Apple
3333    Chery       Cherry
```

To

```
ID      Products        
1111    Apple       
1111    Cherry      
1111    Peach       
2222            
2222            
2222    Apple       
3333    Chery       
3333    Cherry      
3333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *union* query:

```sql
Select ID, [Product 1] As Products
From YourTable
Union All
Select ID, [Product 2] As Products
From YourTable
Union All
Select ID, [Product 3] As Products
From YourTable
Order By ID, Products
```

Comment: One other question I added about 50 products, and the query works, but making a table yields "too complex" probably because there are 50 select statements.  Any way to reduce it so I can make a table from the query?

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. The next problem is that you deal with the database as if it was a spreadsheet. You will have to read up on _how to normalize a database_.

Comment: Yeah this is an inherited excel file and wont be used long term.  So this process is helping get out of the way its currently set up.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK. A trick could be to create and save, say, five union queries and then create yet a union query that unions the five union queries.

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL and a new column for each of the queries to get the correct order:

```
select t.ID, t.Products 
from (
  select 1 AS col, ID, product1 AS Products  from tablename
  union all
  select 2, ID, product2 from tablename
  union all
  select 3, ID, product3 from tablename
) AS t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.col
```

Results:

```
ID      Products
1111    Apple
1111    Cherry
1111    Peach
2222    
2222    
2222    Apple
3333    Cherry
3333    Cherry
3333
```